# Restore Enterprise DB error

Tags: magento-enterprise, database, mysql, ee-1.13

> ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 999: Access denied; you need (at least one
>   of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

I want to restore a production DB to a DEV server, I don't have access to root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the DEFINER= fixed the problem.

```
sed -i ’s/db_org/db_new/g’ current_file.sql
```

I also had to change the 'localhost' to '%'

Not sure you will need to do this.

Comment: You need to remove the DEFINER=xxx@yyyy.com from the dump. MySQL is exporting original DB Trigger owner for database triggers.

Comment: Thanks Macki - Not sure what is easier, removing or replacing ? Especially if the file is 40 gb

Comment: you might have backed up too many tables if you got 40gb. like log_visitor etc. Or back data and structure separately, i think the definer is part of structure.